# Swap two values in an indexed field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is there a simple way (using a SQL query or VBA with a DAO recordset) to swap two values in an indexed field? In my case said field is the primary key of a small table (not expected to exceed 30 records). Expected input and output below.

Before:

```
 StageNumber | Description
 ------------+--------------------------
  01         | First Thing
  02         | Second Thing
```

After:

```
 StageNumber | Description
 ------------+--------------------------
  02         | First Thing
  01         | Second Thing
```

I'm aware this looks like I could simply switch the descriptions rather than the StageNumber but the StageNumber is used as a foreign key into another table with cascading updates specified in the relationship so simply switching the description would cause 'child' records to be associated with the wrong 'parent'.

Ideally this would be achieved with a single `UPDATE..SET` query but for the life of me I can't figure out what the syntax for such an operation would be without causing a primary key violation error.

Comment: You could drop the constraints, update it and then recreate the constraints. Have you tried that?

Comment: By switching them, aren't you corrupting the data to which parent the child records are already linked? You say switching them would correct everything, but what does that say about your current data?

Comment: @Invent-Animate If I change the index value in this table, cascading updates should update the foreign key in the corresponding child records, preserving the parent-child relationship correctly.

Comment: @ChristianBarron No I haven't tried that, but it sounds a bit iffy as far as good practices go. I have a few workarounds in mind for the problem but I was wondering if there was a simple solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Oh! I totally misread that if that was your intent, sorry about that. Why don't you just switch the children records, `WHERE StageNumber_FK = 1` make it 2, `WHERE StageNumber_FK = 2`, make it 1. That's what you're really trying to do, right? Why mess with the parent?

Comment: @Invent-Animate The child records are largely irrelevant to my question, as StuartLC's answer points out I'm fallen somewhat afoul of using a natural key as a primary key, but really the problem would remain the same even if this wasn't a primary key fields and was simply an indexed field with no duplicates allowed.

Comment: They are irrelevant, but you say that one reason you don't alter the descriptions in your parent table is because of the child records? Does that really render them irrelevant if you're avoiding a simple solution because of this irrelevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highlights one of the perils of using a Natural Keys as a primary key, when there is a risk of change of identity.

Assuming there might be similar changes in future, an alternative is to add a new Surrogate PK to the `Stage` table (e.g. `ID` as an integer `AUTONUMBER`), and then:

- Add a new `StageId` foreign key column to all tables referencing `Stage`.
- Then update the `StageId` column to assign the correct `StageId` via a lookup join via the existing foreign key (`StageNo`)
- Then drop the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the existing `StageNumber` foreign key columns in the referencing tables.
- Drop the `PRIMARY KEY` on `Stage.StageNumber` and change the PK to `Stage.Id`
- Then re-add the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the new `StageId` foreign key columns in the referencing tables.

You are now free to change the value of the `StageNumber` column as it is no longer part of a foreign key.

Comment: Even if the StageNumber isn't a primary key I want it to be indexed with no duplicates, so won't I run into the same issues?

Comment: Yes, you can still create a [Unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx) on `StageNumber` after usurping it as the primary key

Comment: Okay, let's forget for a moment that my field is a primary key, I've probably sent people down the completely wrong track with that info. Assuming StageNumber was an indexed field of type integer with no duplicates permitted, how could I swap the StageNumbers of two records without causing an index violation? I'm aware that using a meaningful primary key can be fallacious, but your answer doesn't demonstrate clearly how making it simply an indexed field would allow me to easily perform a 'swap value' operation.

Comment: `In my case said field is the primary key of a small table` ;) - If it wasn't part of a key, then the "swap through temporary" approach will suffice, i.e.  assign a new unique value to the row (`UPDATE Stage Set StageNumber = '999' WHERE StageNumber = '01';` then `UPDATE Stage Set StageNumber = '01' WHERE StageNumber = '02';` then `UPDATE Stage Set StageNumber = '02' WHERE StageNumber = '999';`

Answer (score 0):

Update StageNumber of the first record to an arbitrary number not in use.

Update StageNumber of the second record to that the first record had.

Update StageNumber of the first record to that the second records had.

Or, in two steps:

Update both StageNumbers to arbitrary numbers not in use.

Update both StageNumbers to that the other record had.